# How to find that site is easily navigable for the user using google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, analytics, google-tag-manager

If it is a case of user acceptability test , the usability metric will be calculated using the formula  U = N((1-(1-L))^n , where n = Number of Users, N = Total Number of Usability Problems in the design , L = is the proportion of the  usability problems found /discovered while testing in the single user .

But , How do we know that a user of the web page is facing some 
problem and challenge  using Google Tag Manager .

How to we find that "user got the information from the webpage with satisfaction " using google tag manager ... then How to we find that the information on the web page  was relevant ?